# Find $2$ values of $\theta$ such that $0\le\theta<2\pi$ and $5 \sin \theta + 6 \cos \theta = 0$

Tags: calculus, trigonometry

> Find $2$ values of $\theta$ such that $0\le\theta<2\pi$ and $5 \sin \theta + 6 \cos \theta = 0$

So far for this question I have $\tan\theta = 5/6$. Not too sure what to do this with this information on the unit circle to find $\theta$.

Comment: I assume you meant $\tan\theta = \frac{5}{6}$.  However, you should check your calculations.  Have you found the inverse tangent of your angle.  What is the period of the tangent function?

Comment: Take out your calculator and punch in $\arctan \frac 56$.  That's one of them.  What's the other?

Answer (score 2):

Of course from $5\sin\theta + 6 \cos \theta =0$ we get
$$5 \sin \theta = -6\cos \theta$$ which gives after dividing by $5 \cos\theta$ that

$$\tan \theta = -\frac{6}{5}$$

which you can solve (numerically, get the claculator out). $\tan$ has period $\pi$ so add $\pi$ (or subtract $\pi$) to find another one. You get a negative first one, so adding $\pi$ gets you the first one, adding another $\pi$ the second one. There are two points on the unit circle that qualify. [Wolfram alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=arctan%28-6+%2F5%29+) can help too.